# Rails Backend And React Frontend Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-activestorage

I use ActiveStorage to store one image per product. When I show the list of products I managed to display the image of each product. Now when I want to display the individual information in another form the following problem arises:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Controller:

```rb
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    @products = Product.all
    render json: @products
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    render json: @product
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      render json: @product, status: :created
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    raise params.inspect
    if @product.update(product_params)
      render json: @product, status: :ok
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  
  private

  def product_params
    params.permit(:name, :price,:image_product)
  end
end
```

Serializer:

```rb
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  attributes :id, :name, :price, :image_product

  def image_product
    if object.image_product.attached?
      {
        url: rails_blob_url(object.image_product)
      }
    end
  end

end
```

Form with the problem:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';

class ProductInfo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { product: {} };
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`api/v1/products/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())  
      .then(data => {
          this.setState({product: data});
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }

  handleDelete() {
    fetch(`api/v1/products/${this.props.match.params.id}`, {method: 'DELETE'})
      .then(() => {
        this.props.history.push("/products")
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { console.log('Estamos en el show')} 
        { console.log(this.state.product.image_product)}  
        <h2> {this.state.product.name}</h2>
        <p>{this.state.product.price}</p>
        
        <CardMedia
        image={this.state.product.image_product.url}
        title={this.state.product.name}
        />

        {/* <img src={this.state.product.image_product.url} alt={this.state.product.name} > </img> */}
        <p>
          <Link to={`/products/${this.state.product.id}/edit`} className="btn btn-outline-dark">Edit</Link> 
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete} className="btn btn-outline-dark">Delete</button> 
          <Link to="/products" className="btn btn-outline-dark">Close</Link>
        </p>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductInfo;
```

This is what I get with `{ console.log(this.state.product) }`:

```
{ id: 49, name: "Lavarropa", price: 12321, image_product: {…} }
```

This is what I get with `{ console.log(this.state.product.image_product) }`:

```
{ url: "http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/r…e01385eb070514fe1bcf226b7ea4c92de05/Lavarropa.jpg"}
```

I do not know how to identify what type of object is what it returns, I use `typeof` but it says that it is an object only.

The problem is when I use:

```
.url
```

Since the object is undefined, surely it is something simple but for me it is not.

Comment: Your initial state does not have the same shape as what you get from the API (in React, the details of the Rails app are totally irrelevant here). Either give a matching initial state or show something different until the data has actually loaded.

Comment: OK thanks. But what would be the solution?

Comment: I already gave two. _"Either give a matching initial state", i.e. one that has the same shape as what you're expecting from the API, _"or show something different"_, e.g. a loading message, _"until the data has actually loaded."_

Comment: Dear, I am a newbie to the subject, so I would appreciate it if you can translate it to me in code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it, apparently React renders when fetching and also in other cases. So when doing the fetch it renders and the object is undefined, hence the error.
So when loading the form I had to perform the following validation:

```
if this.state.product.id !== undefined 
 imagen = this.state.product.image_product.url
else
 imagen = '' /*You could put an image that reports that it is empty./*
end
```

That way if it's empty it doesn't show anything.
Greetings and thanks for the help although it was not much this time jaja.